# Return focus to the Word editor after action in Add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js

We have a Microsoft Word add-in which uses the Javascript API. This add-in allows the user to insert Content Controls. Once the control is added, we want to return focus to the editor (Word document) so the user can immediately continue typing.

Currently, the control is being added with `select('End')`; however, focus still remains in the add-in until the user clicks back into the document.

Is there any way to return focus to the document and away from the add-in's task pane once this control is added?

Comment: I suppose this is currently by design since you just operated on the Add-in pane, so the focus is still there.

Comment: Believe me, I know – it makes sense from that perspective. However, most likely our users would want to immediately begin typing again in the document after this action, so it would be very handy if they didn't have do make another click before that was possible. The selection is in the correct place, there's just no equivalent focus() type method unfortunately.

Comment: it is truly remarkable how stunted this design is, I am in total awe.. I just spent hours developing a new add-in and realised that this extremely limiting problem exists.. appalling..